# How android service responds when stopped by system

Tags: android, service

I have a question related to how Android service behaves when stopped by system. As per my understanding, if system (OS) stops the service due to resources needed, it is responsibility of system to start it again. In this scenario, system would not call onDestroy() when stopping service and onCreate() when starting service, rather it would just call onStartCommand().

If I am creating a thread in onStartCommand(), how would I cleanup thread when system stops service. If I dont stop thread, onStartCommand() would create a new thread.
I think, it may come down to onStartCommand() parameters (intent, flags and startId). They might be different when system starts service after stopping it because it needed resources. Could anyone tell me what would be difference in parameters when service started by startService() command or by system itself (after stopping it)

I can create thread in onCreate() but I am not sure if thread still exists when system stops service. What would be the best way to handle this kind of scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per my understanding, if system (OS) stops the service due to resources needed, it is responsibility of system to start it again.

That depends upon what you return from `onStartCommand()`. `START_NOT_STICKY`, for example, means the OS does not have to start your service again.

> In this scenario, system would not call onDestroy() when stopping service and onCreate() when starting service, rather it would just call onStartCommand().

Whether it calls `onDestroy()` would depend a bit on how the service is stopped (e.g., directly or via process termination). However, it should still call `onCreate()` on the new instance, if and when the OS restarts the service.

> If I am creating a thread in onStartCommand(), how would I cleanup thread when system stops service.

Ensure that in `onDestroy()`, something happens that will cause the thread to go away. Either `onDestroy()` will be called (and your service can do its cleanup), or your process is being terminated (and your thread goes away with it).

> Could anyone tell me what would be difference in parameters when service started by startService() command or by system itself (after stopping it)

There is a `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` that will be in the flags passed to `onStartCommand()`, but AFAIK it will only be set if you return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. So, you are saying that System would always call onCreate() regardless of how service was stopped. Unfortunately, I have seen instances (through logging) when system stops service but doesn't call onDestroy() or onCreate() and directly calls onStartCommand(). How would I handle those scenarios?

Comment: @bsengar: "Unfortunately, I have seen instances (through logging) when system stops service but doesn't call onDestroy() or onCreate() and directly calls onStartCommand()" -- you are welcome to provide a sample app and steps for reproducing the problem that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: You can easily test it by writing a sample service and logging on onCreate(), onStartCommand() and onDestroy(). start the service at boot-up. Check service status after about 10 hours (or may be more), it might say that service running for 2 hours. But if you check log file, you cannot see any onDestroy() or onCreate() calls, rather just additional onStartCommand() calls.

Comment: @bsengar: What, precisely, is "check service status"? If you are uninterested in supplying a sample app that demonstrates your problem, nobody else is likely to be interested in helping you.

Comment: apologies commonsware for confusion..what i meant was checking service status in running application (which tells how long service is running for). Even if device boot time was 10 hours before (thats when service started), sometimes, running application status shows service running for, say 2 hours (instead of 10 hours). It means service was stopped at least one in between, so I should have got onDestroy() and onCreate() calls in log file, however I only get onStartCommand() call. I hope it make sense. I dont have sample application at the moment, but would write one and attach.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using a accessibility service and if i kill the app from running applications the system is taking away the accessibility permission that user explicitly gave and that leads me to ask for permission again. Any explanation why this is happening and some solution to avoid this problem.

Comment: @dirtydexter: I have no idea. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question on this.